# Qt Combo box with Check able not working

Tags: qt

I have created a QCombobox with checkable items in Qt according to this [link](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/ModelView/ComboBoxOfCheckBoxes). But it works only when i apply QPlastiqueStyle .This style does not work in QT5. What should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I found to solve this problem was to create a custom Widget using QListWidget and QButtons and then promoting my QCombobox to the Custom widget.